# How to find common rows between two dataframe in R and remove them

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have two dataframes with different number of rows.

`df1` is longer than `df2`, they both share several common rows.

My example

```
df1 <- data.frame(name1 = "a", "b", "c",
                 name2 = "a1","b1","c1",
                 name3 = "a2","b2","c2") 
df1
  name1 name2 name3
1     a    a1    a2
2     b    b1    b2
3     c    c1    c2

df2 <- data.frame(name1 = c("a", "b", "m"),
                  name2 = c("a3","b3", "m1"),
                  name3 = c("a4", "b4", "m2"))
df2
  name1 name2  name3
1     a    a3     a4
2     b    b3     b4
3     m    m1     m2
```

I would like to exclude the common rows in two dataframe and only keep one row of `df2` in this case using `tidyverse`. Any suggestion for this?

Desired output

```
name1 name2 name3
    m    m1    m2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `anti_join` (originally posted as comments way before the other answer was posted)

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("name1"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name1 = c("a", "b", "c"), name2 = c("a1", "b1", 
"c1"), name3 = c("a2", "b2", "c2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(name1 = c("a", "b"), name2 = c("a3", "b3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
anti_join(df1, df2, by = "name1")

  name1 name2 name3
1     c    c1    c2


anti_join(df2, df1, by = "name1")

  name1 name2 name3
1     m    m1    m2
```